# Transform coordinates in the city with openstreetmap api

Tags: javascript, api, openstreetmap

Can I convert latitude and longitude in a city address using the OpenStreetMap API? Can you also retrieve the province and the region or should I use external databases for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you want to convert it to? Do you want to do Geocoding where you get the latitude and longitude for a city or an address? If that's the case u can use the Nominatim service provided by OSM: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim